# error in converting numeric values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2014-express

```
Sql Table : stocks

Colomn Name    |  Data Type
------------------------------
Stock_no       |  nvarchar(15)
Quantity       |  int 
Gem.Weight     |  float
Cost           |  decimal(18,2)
```

My stock insert form code:

```
private void stocks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Stocks VALUES('" + txt_stock_no.Text + "', '"
             + txt_qty.Text + "','" + txt_gem_weight.Text + "', '" + txt_cost.Text + "')", conn);

        MessageBox.Show("You've inserted successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);                 
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I think the the error should be with my '.text' has issues.. i tried making changing with it even though its not working.

Comment: Help you with what? You forgot to tell us your actual problem and also you might want to choose either java or c#.

Comment: What is the error message. it should be `VALUES(" + txt_stock_no.Text + " ` instead of `VALUES('" + txt_stock_no.Text + "'` BTW you should parameterized query to do so

Comment: Please read up on SQL Injection. This code is vulnerable.

Comment: The **very first** thing to do is stop building your SQL like this. Use parameterized SQL, *always*. The approach you're using is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - if you don't know what they are, read up on them before going any further. I strongly suspect that if you start using parameters, the problem will just go away...

Comment: how to convert this '" + txt_cost.Text + "' to numeric format. so that my data will be inserted properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: share your error please

Comment: Using SQL parameters will solve your problem, by forcing you to convert the Text properties beforehand. And it's an important security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't insert values directly from text boxes, your code is vulnerable to [**SQL Injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) this way.
- You have to validate the user inputs for these values from the text boxes. For example, the text box `txt_stock_no` should allow only integer values.
- It would be better to list also the columns' names in the insert statement, not just the values, in case you missed or forget the order of them. and also for readability.
- Then, Use [**Parameterized-Queries**](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Parameterized-Queries-ADO.Net.aspx).

Something like this:

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO Stocks VALUES(@stock_no, @txt_qty,@txt_gem_weight,@txt_cost)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@stock_no", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@stock_no"].Value = txt_stock_no.Text;

    ....
    // do the same for other parameters
}
```

**Update:**:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
command.Parameters.Add("@stock_no", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@stock_no"].Value = txt_stock_no.Text;

....
// do the same for other parameters
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR SHARING THIS

Comment: I WILL INSERT THIS WAY, HOPE IT WORKS

Comment: i am getting an error for this 'connectionString' only

Comment: Line
Error CS0103 The name 'connectionString' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @nikiminisileen `connectionString` is the your database connection string, the one you passed to your variable `conn`.

Comment: @nikiminisileen - You can remove it and use the code in my updated answer.

Comment: please one last question... you have given me a code for an integer datatype right which means Stock_no is an int so the code works.. how will it work for a varchar value and decemal (18,2). please help me

Answer (score -2):

Replace your code with this:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Stocks VALUES('" + txt_stock_no.Text + "', "+ txt_qty.Text + "," + txt_gem_weight.Text + "," + txt_cost.Text + ")", conn);
int rowseffected=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//rest of your code goes here...
```

> However, this is not recommended. This is query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters instead, you will not face issue like this again.

Comment: However, this is not recommended. This is query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters instead, you will not face issue like again.

Comment: Wrong. Parameters are nowhere here, and the Text property will be  converted using whichever locale the OP is using.

Comment: @Steve, use of parameters is not a question here. nikimini is asking why this query is not working. I am answering to that only. He is not using ORM also. So, should I point that also?

Comment: In that case you are also wrong steve. Use of ORM like hibernate is nowhere here. They are much much better than use of paramters :-P

Comment: You are teaching a very wrong way to create an SQL command. You should never do that and explain why the OP shouldn't do it in that way. By the way if the user types "111,15" (comma instead of a point for decimals) the result of the automatic conversion executed by the db engine could be very wrong (and we don't even start talking about dates conversion)

Comment: error says: ERROR CONVERTING DATA TYPE VARCHAR TO NUMERIC